# How did bombs fall into the Dreadnought?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

If there is no gravity in space.

How can they use gravity to throw bombs into the Dreadnought in the first scene on the movie?

Comment: There **is** gravity in space...it might be really weak but there's gravity everywhere...

Comment: Why the thumbs down?, I think is a legit question.

Comment: Also, there's no back/forth/up/down in space, so the bombers could have flown on the top of target and launched the bombs directly from there.

Comment: @AlessandroSanfilippo - Good questions get random downvotes. It's not something you should worry about unless they start coming in multiples of more than one.

Comment: Any clues on how Rose's sister survived with nothing between her and open space?

Comment: @Allball103 I think that needs its own question hahahaha.

Comment: @Allball103 Not very well at all.  But do we know she *wouldn't* have suffocated if the bomber hadn't exploded five seconds after she opened the bay doors?  (Or were they opened earlier?  If that's the case, my guess is "force fields")

Comment: They fall using the phenomenon known as the *plot hole* which has less gravity than a *black hole* but more attractive force than zero gravity. ;)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast - Just because you don't like the technobabble explanation doesn't make it a plot

Comment: @Valorum It's the difference between good science fiction and bad. Primary/secondary world features.

Comment: I think Star wars is more of a fantasy movie than Sci-fi. I mean the girl that dropped the bombs was just laying there when the door to space was open, no suction or anything so I don't think science even plays a role here

Comment: A more interesting question is why were bombers even necessary when they clearly have missiles and droids.

Comment: If there were no gravity in space, satellites and spaceships and space stations wouldn't be able to orbit a planet.

Comment: @Kyralessa yeah but in that case, wouldnt the bombs just orbit the planet instead of falling down directly into the ship?

Comment: @AlessandroSanfilippo Not if they weren't going fast enough to orbit.  An object that flies into space (without escaping Earth's gravity well) will just fall back to Earth.  To orbit, the object has to have as much "horizontal" velocity as gravity would impart to it "vertically".  Orbiting a planet is essentially endlessly falling without getting any lower.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Plot Holes can be stronger than Black Holes. I have actually seen them in a number of times.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A recent [tweet](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/946591989629272064) from the head of the Star Wars Story Group, Pablo Hidalgo would suggest that (artificial) gravity plays its part in getting the bombs out of the magazine.

> *There's gravity on the bomber. We saw a person fall and a remote
>   control fall. **That's really all you need to get the bombs to fall out
>   the bottom and then keep falling.***

[The Last Jedi: The Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) indicates however that the bombs are repulsed from the rack by electro-magnetism (like a rail gun) and then drawn to their metal target by magnetic attraction.

> *Bombs don't technically "drop" in microgravity, but are impelled from
>   their racks by sequenced electromagnetic plates in the clip. The bombs
>   are then drawn magnetically to their unfortunate targets.*

We can square this circle by imagining that the lowest bombs (which only fall a few metres in gravity) are given an additional *boost* by the magnets, in order to get them moving fast enough that the topmost bombs (which fall 20+ meters) don't end up ploughing into them.

[image]

Comment: Aw.  I was figuring they used the dreadnought's own artificial gravity field.  Would have served 'em right for breaking the laws of physics. :-)

Comment: While that answer is appreciated, and up voted, that's not good science fiction in its implementation on screen: bombs should have been seen to accelerate if that was the force at work. (Yeah, one can spend all day rolling one's eyes at the "science" in the SF of Star Wars).

Comment: Though not addressed by The Visual Dictionary, another point would be that the ships in space are not in orbit and not in free fall. A 2.9-kilometer long Resurgent-class Star Destroyer that appears to be 1-degree wide to a viewer on the surface would be at an altitude of about 166 kilometers and subject to ~.95g. If you release a bomb above it, the bomb will fall.

Comment: Some people wondered how the bombs tell apart their target and the bomber than launched them - well, the target will pretty much always be made out of metal, while the bombers themselves are made from paper.

Comment: @Petersaber - I presume the bombs are sufficient "smart" to orient themselves down (and hence away from the bomber).

Comment: @Valorum I was making a joke :)

Comment: @Petersaber - Too subtle for me, sorry.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast "not good science fiction in its implementation on screen" can describe that whole movie pretty well...

Answer (score 19):

It looked like they used inertia. The bomber has gravity inside it (which was a minor plot point, with the pilot falling and then knocking the remote down). They hit the release and whatever gravity it uses pulls the bombs out. Since there's no air in space, the bombs simply continue on their trajectory until they hit something.

Comment: A good guess, but unfortunately wrong.

Comment: There was enough air to enable the pilot to keep breathing as she was kicking the ladder.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP There was a force field to keep the air in. They're pretty far outside the atmosphere of the planet

Comment: You didn't spot that the bombs were _within_ said force field at that point, then.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP I don't get what you're saying. Yes, the bombs are inside air inside the ship. They're also within gravity. Once the bombs leave the bay, they're no longer inside air...

Comment: @JdeBP - the Star Wars universe makes regular use of forcefields that can hold air in, but allow objects to pass through -- every time a ship opens a hangar door to space to let spacecraft in/out, there are people in the hangar that are apparently breathing at normal air pressure yet the ship makes its way through the forcefield unimpeded.

Comment: @Johnny : indeed, airlocks seem to not have been invented in that galaxy.

Comment: @vsz - When you have gas-impermeable forcefields, airlocks are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

As well as having some kind of artificial gravity on the bomber, there were other sources of gravity-like forces.

The battle was over a planet, but it's not clear if the ships were in orbit of it. They could have been falling towards it.

The First Order dreadnaught also had artificial gravity inside, and it's not clear how far outside that extends. Certainly Poe Dameron didn't seem to be experiencing zero gravity effects inside his ship from what we could see, although it too may have had a gravity generator of some kind.