# Why did the Resistance bombers fly this way?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In the opening sequence of The Last Jedi, we observe

> a squadron of Resistance bombers flying in fairly close formation towards the First Order dreadnaught. Arguably, the bombers arm their ordnance quite prematurely and fly irresponsibly close to each other, the result being that when one ship is destroyed it practically wipes out the whole squadron.

So my question is:

**Why did the Resistance bombers fly in such close formation and arm their bombs so early?**

EDIT: I don't see this as a duplicate of [Why arm the bombs early?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176766/why-arm-the-bombs-early) because this question primarily addresses the flying formation of the squadron.

Comment: Because that way would've led them to trouble.

Comment: In real life, all bombs have safety mechanisms such that they are not truly armed until they are some distance away from the bomber (as measured by some scheme such as: air speed, barometric pressure, rotation, acceleration, etc.).  Also, even fully armed bombs do not chain react that way.  Military bombs are designed to be pretty safe for [a wide range of pre-firing conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA6bG.jpg).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why arm the bombs early?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176766/why-arm-the-bombs-early)

Comment: The proposed duplicate does not answer the question in the title (or the first part of the question in the text).

Comment: Because Johnson wanted a WW2 bombing run sequence. That's the only reason. God, I hate this sequence with passion.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The question of why they're so close to each other is dealt with in the [Last Jedi: Incredible Cross-Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Incredible_Cross-Sections) factbook. In short it's because they rely on overlapping fields of fire to prevent small fighters from getting too close, using [much the same tactics as bombers in our own galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combat_box).

> **STRENGTH IN NUMBERS**
>
> *Bombers are slow and ungainly, leaving them vulnerable to enemy star
>   fighters during attack runs. For protection, they depend not just on
>   fighter escorts but also on each other. **Resistance flight instructors
>   teach bomber pilots that it is essential to fly in a tight formation,
>   opposing attacking fighters with overlapping fields of fire.** The rear
>   and ventral turrets offer a potent defence against attackers
>   approaching from below or from the rear, but are less effective
>   against threats from above or in front of the bomber squadron.*

The bombs themselves weren't armed until the bombers were directly over the nose of the dreadnought (pictured below) and were within mere seconds of being dropped. It was just bad luck that this happened at almost exactly the same time as a TIE wing ploughed through the bomb bay of one of the bombers, causing a chain-reaction.

[image]

Comment: I'd also assume that dropping all your loads in the same area has a larger impact than dropping spread out across the target

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Probably some were going to drop almost immediately.

Comment: Can I propose an edit to add that the Resistance bomber formation was probably built to create the imagery of a B-17 formation as often depicted in ww2 material (where most of the space combat is drawn from). The bombers are even named SF-17s for goodness sake. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combat_box

Comment: Also, the SF stands for StarFortress evocative of the names of the B-29 Superfortress and B-52 Stratofortress. The B-17 was called the Flying Fortress.

Comment: @vynsane right? I'm half surprised they didn't name the X-Wings T-47 and new A-Wings as T-51D it's almost too blatant at this point, as soon as I saw that formation appear on screen I knew exactly what they were trying to do.

Comment: Heh, unfortunately, T-47 was already used for the Snowspeeders on Hoth. The OT X-wings were T-65s and the new ones are T-70s.

Comment: Love how the complaint is formation and not "dropping bombs" in a vacuum.

Comment: @alemus - ["How did bombs fall into the Dreadnought?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176403/how-did-bombs-fall-into-the-dreadnought)

Comment: You're probably better off not including that image; it's impossible to tell what it's depicting due to how dark (and cropped) the shot is.

Comment: @alemus Objects in space still have mass and mass has gravitational pull. Additionally, these ships actually produce their own artificial gravity so that might add a 'pull' on any nearby objects, especially comparatively tiny ones like the bombs.

Comment: @Rapscallion some back-of-envelope calcs would quickly show that the mass of a bomber wouldn't accelerate the bombs at anywhere near a practical speed, and certainly far from as fast as depicted. I choose to believe that the 'drop' involves a launching mechanism, and the verb 'dropping' is just being hijacked from ground-based bombing techniques. This would distinguish 'firing' a missile from 'dropping' an explosive with no propulsion of its own. *Edit - see [How did bombs fall into the Dreadnought](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176403/23347) *

Comment: @brichins I was referring to the mass of the Star Destroyer pulling the bombs towards it, but yes, it does appear that the ships have a sort of firing mechanism.EDIT: Technically the bomber could drop the bombs behind it while in a dive, then pull up, allowing the bombs to carry on towards the target.

Comment: @alemus the bombs were on rails, they were pushed out. Like a slow railgun. The formation was nonsensical, and... if they're already a railgun bombs, why is it a slow railgun...

Comment: @Petersaber - Because if it was a fast railgun, they might explode in the magazine.

Comment: @Valorum How exactly would that happen? The bombs were already dropped in some kind of a sequence. Just program a proper sequence.

Comment: @Rapscallion - Per my earlier comment, the factbook is 100% clear that the bombs are *magnetic*; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176403/how-did-bombs-fall-into-the-dreadnought

Comment: @Valorum magnetic?! That's terrible. That makes even less sense. Jesus Christ I hate those bombers even more now.

Comment: @Petersaber - There have been attempts for years to make railgun-fired ordnance a reality. One of the key problems has been that when accelerated to a useful speed, the shells have tendency to blow up in the barrel.

Comment: @Valorum Railguns are not a problem in SW universe. Weren't they ancient and considered primitive? Anyway, I am not talking about a "5000km/h" kind of fast railgun, more like "500km/h".

Comment: In addition to overlapping fields of fire, the tight formation allows the Resistance fighter escort to protect the bombers from TIE fighters. If the bombers and their escort were more spread out, there's a danger the TIEs could swoop in and concentrate their attacks on one bomber at a time before the escort fighters could react.