# Does Ahch-To actually have two suns?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

At the end of *The Last Jedi*,

> Luke sees a sunset with two (2!) suns, which beautifully calls back to his contemplative scene on Tatooine in ANH. I pointed out after watching it that I thought it was just in Luke's mind, but everyone I was with didn't see it that way (not at first, anyway).

Is there any canon info that says one way or another whether Ahch-To has two suns or whether this was just

> what Luke saw in his mind as he became one with the Force?

Comment: Bear in mind that [the majority of stars are actually twins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_star). This isn't some sort of rare phenomenon, but closer to the norm.

Comment: @terdon From what I read, that's mostly only true of the most massive of stars, but according to [Harvard-Smithsonian Center for Astrophysics](https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/news/2006-11) the vast majority of stars are actually much smaller, and are not in binary or multiple systems. That's not to say they are lonely, these single stars are considered more likely to have orbiting planets.

Comment: Huh, thanks for that. Apparently, I'm out of date and still considered the "common wisdom" mentioned in the link as correct.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach I believe that terdon meant that the "majority" of stars as the majority of what we can easily see. Sure, there are a lot of smaller stars, but would you notice them as easily? Would you notice a tiny Death Star if it were heading towards your capital planet to destroy it? They would think it was a freak accident, so you have to have a BIG GIGANTIC Death Star so they fear it (and, well, you know, practical reasons). But, I digress.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes. The [Last Jedi Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) mentions

> "twin suns"

[image]

As does the film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)

> *Luke opened his eyes and fell onto the ledge, the pebbles plunking
>   down around him. He lay on his back, his breathing ragged with
>   exhaustion. **The twin suns had touched the horizon** and were sinking
>   into the ocean.*

Comment: Awww.  I was hoping that it was something more...still, it was one of my favorite shots in the whole movie.

Comment: what else would it have been? Trick of the light? Him force-projecting to Tatooine for one last sunset?... actually that could've been really cool...

Comment: @WraithLeader - I quite like OP's suggestion that he was imagining the sunset of his youth

Comment: @Valorum The fact that we never saw the twin suns until that final, contemplative scene was certainly deliberate to serve as a reminder of Luke's origins. That there are actually twin suns on Ahch-To does not change the emotional effect that sunset has on us or Luke himself as he joins with the Force.

Comment: Frankly, I always thought Luke saw a vision from his past with the view of twin suns. Finding out that there actually were two stars is kind of disappointing... :(

Comment: Perhaps, there’s still some mysterious connection between these planets, both having two suns, one being especially wet, the other especially dry, one being the place were the Jedi Order was founded, the other being the place were the specially gifted boy was born (Anakin, cough, born without a father)…

Comment: @JakeGould planets orbit the sun(s), not the other way. One planet can have only one speed.

Comment: @Holger technically..... http://oi60.tinypic.com/30wxdeg.jpg

Comment: @CptEric: there’s still no sun orbiting a planet. This constellation allows to see the two suns in the same hemisphere at one time and separated at other times, but it doesn’t change very fast.

Comment: @JakeGould - They were magnetic, dude; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/176486/20774

Comment: @Valorum and I thought they were just propelled by the art-grav in the bomber itself. Oh well. At least I knew it is that way with the Y-Wing. Or is it...?

Answer (score 1):

To add to that, [a second canon source confirms this](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2457537/the-star-wars-the-last-jedi-comic-adds-some-more-insight-into-luke-skywalkers-death?utm_source=followistic&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=followistic#flw_c=email&flw_n=5b9ae5835313545aaea4acc2).

In the new Marvel "the Last Jedi" comic book, Luke's last thought is:

> And so it ends as it began. By the light of two suns.